# manjaro_arm_base_16.08_rpi2_rpi3_berryboot password

Tags: login

What is the default password for the Raspberry Pi 2 image `manjaro_arm_base_16.08_rpi2_rpi3_berryboot`?

I have tried root/root, but that does not work. Could someone tell me what I need to do to log in to this system?

Comment: have you tried pi/raspberry

Comment: Just tried it and to no avail. I also tried going to the website to get more support, but it seems that there is no documentation on the default password. root/root does not work either. root/root not working. manjaro_arm_base_16.08_rpi2_rpi3_berryboot was the image I loaded on my PI 2.

Comment: Are you logging in via `ssh` or with display/keyboard attached?

Comment: Where did you get the image from?

Answer (score 1):

Per [manjaro's wiki](http://wiki.manjaro-arm.org/index.php?title=Full_New_Users_Installation_guide) it should be:

> root / root

and

> manjaro / manjaro

Comment: tried root/root, manjaro/manjaro, root/toor, etc. Still not working. I also tried to re-download it and reimage the card. Still not letting me login. Seems funny that it could be a problem with berryboot, but I don't think that is the problem.